# WPF ListBox style with data template

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a problem with databinding, data template and my own style of a WPF ListBox. I created a style for a ListBox with some column definitions to get a better view. See screenshot:
[image]

Here is the XAML code of my ListView:

```xaml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Org.Vs.TailForWin.LogView"
    xmlns:business="clr-namespace:Org.Vs.TailForWin.Business.Data"
    >
    <Style x:Key="NumberLinesStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Index, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="NumberLinesTemplate" DataType="{x:Type business:LogEntry}">
        <TextBlock
            Margin="5,1"
            Style="{StaticResource NumberLinesStyle}"
            />
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type local:LogWindowListBox}" TargetType="{x:Type local:LogWindowListBox}">
        <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ItemStyle}" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:LogWindowListBox}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ScrollViewer
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            CanContentScroll="True"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                            >
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Border
                                    x:Name="BorderBookmark"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Width="20"
                                    Background="DarkGray"
                                    />

                                <Border
                                    x:Name="BorderLineNumber"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    MinWidth="80"
                                    BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
                                    >
                                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <VisualBrush>
                                            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                <Rectangle
                                                    Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                                    Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                                    Stroke="Black"
                                                    StrokeDashArray="2 6"
                                                    StrokeThickness="0.7"
                                                    />
                                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                        </VisualBrush>
                                    </Border.BorderBrush>

                                    <ContentPresenter
                                        x:Name="NumberLineContentControl"
                                        Content="{Binding}"
                                        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NumberLinesTemplate}"
                                        />
                                </Border>

                                <ItemsPresenter Grid.Column="3" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

My problem is the ContentPresenter. In Visual Studio Debug output comes the following error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Index' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=31201899)'. BindingExpression:Path=Index; DataItem='MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=31201899); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

How have to look the binding of the ContentPresenter, to take the right value from my collection? In the main window my binding looks so:

```xaml
    <Grid>
        <logView:LogWindowListBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding LogEntries}"
            behaviors:ListBoxSelector.Enabled="True"
            />
    </Grid>
```

LogEntries is a ObservableCollection in MainWindowViewModel.
A second problem is the selection. I want, that the user can set a selection within the BorderLineNumber column. But at the moment it does not work. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: ListView is a ListBox with columns

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong, change to TemplateBinding ItemsSource

```
<ContentPresenter
  x:Name="NumberLineContentControl"
  **Content="{Binding}"**
```